# Timeseries - Appending Growth Data by Row Sequentailly

Tags: r, function, dplyr, iteration

I am new(ish) to R and am looking for help with a question. I have searched on stackoverflow for a similar question quite a bit, but it is definitely possible I am searching using the wrong words.

What I would like to do is in simple terms, do an equation sequentially over rows with dplyr pipes, such that the result in one row depends on the value in the row before it.

For the purposes of this discussion, I have created a sample data frame (named, sample):

```
> sample
# A tibble: 10 x 4
    year variable variable_growth_rates other_growth_rates
   <dbl>    <dbl>                 <dbl>              <dbl>
 1  2010    20000              NA                   NA    
 2  2011    23450               0.173                0.15 
 3  2012    25110               0.0708               0.12 
 4  2013    25350               0.00956              0.105
 5  2014    24920              -0.0170               0.075
 6  2015    25010               0.00361              0.05 
 7  2016       NA              NA                    0.025
 8  2017       NA              NA                    0.032
 9  2018       NA              NA                    0.041
10  2019       NA              NA                    0.071
```

I want to apply the growth rates in other_growth_rates to column variable from the last year of data only, keeping the historical data. I've tried loops, apply and also my own function, but I suspect my skills with these are terrible, so I'm just not able to get them to work.

I can do long form:

```
##### Append Growth rates from variable other_growth_rates to our historical data in variable
sample_rvsd <- sample %>%
  mutate(variable_rvsd = ifelse(!is.na(variable), 
variable, lag(variable)*(1+other_growth_rates))) %>%
  mutate(variable_rvsd = ifelse(!is.na(variable), variable, lag(variable)*(1+other_growth_rates))) %>%  
  mutate(variable_rvsd = ifelse(!is.na(variable), variable, lag(variable)*(1+other_growth_rates))) %>% 
  mutate(variable_rvsd = ifelse(!is.na(variable), variable, lag(variable)*(1+other_growth_rates)))
```

This is fine if there are only a few years and one variable, but I need to do this with multiple variables and over ten plus years. It's also a problem I run into frequently, so I can see my code getting messy in a hurry.

I tried to write a function - which I think would be optimal (as I do need to do this frequently). Again, my skills aren't great:

Write append_growth function

```
# Function
append_growth <- function(x, y) {
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    x_new <- ifelse(!is.na(x), x, lag(x) * y)
  }
}

##### Apply growth rates function
sample_rvsd_fail <- sample %>%
  mutate(variable_rvsd = append_growth(variable, other_growth_rates))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to go about doing this, so below is just one answer using base R. I did it in base because it most closely resembled how you started out. You mentioned wanting to do this in dplyr which would be a great way to go about this. Check out the documentation on [mutate_at/mutate_if](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html).

```
sample <- data.frame(year = c(2010:2019),
                     variable = c(20000, 23450, 25110, 25350, 24920, 25010, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                     variable_growth_rates = c(NA, .173, .0708, .00956, -.0170, .00361, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                     other_growth_rates = c(NA, .15, .12, .105, .075, .05, .025, .032, .041, .071))


append_growth <- function(data, variable, rate){
  for(x in 1:nrow(data)){
    data[x, variable] <- ifelse(is.na(data[x, variable]), 
                                    (data[x-1, variable]*(1+data[x, rate])), data[x, variable])
  }
  data
}

df <- append_growth(sample, "variable", "other_growth_rates")
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfect - across multiple different dataframes. I will check out mutate_at as suggested. For now, I like the function, as it minimizes the coding I need to do in each example.